# Shortest distance between two points moving with the same speed on two lines

Tags: parametric

I have homework that I have to solve, and the my question is:
A cube has side length of 2 cm. One ant starts at corner A and travels to corner B.
Another ant starts at corner C and travels to corner D. The two ants leave at the same time and travel at the same speed. Find the shortest distance between the two ants.
[image: Question figure]
and my solution:
[image: Solution Pic]
I don't know if my answer is correct, is it?

Comment: The lines are not paralell (even thogh you say they are)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions, instead of posting images.

Comment: It shoud be $+12$ instead of $+8$.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos for your advice, I have edited the question, could you check it out.

Comment: @O-BL I've edited your question, but it would be better if you would type your solution.

Comment: @JohnMa Thank you, I have edited my solution could you reload? and check if it correct? and I will be thankful! :)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, actually I don't know how to format the formulas, so I think i would keep an image.

Comment: @O-BL Please read the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Check your expressions at $t=0$ and $t=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second ant is at $(2,2,-2t)$.

The squared distance is

$$(2t-2)^2+(-2)^2+(2t)^2=8(t^2-t+1).$$

By completing the square, the minimum is achieved at $t=\dfrac12$, when the ants are at the midpoints, and the distance is $\sqrt6$.

Comment: By the way, it is easier/safer to write the coordinates of the ants by simple inspection than by error-prone computation of the line coefficients.

Comment: Could you explain a little further? I believe that the second ant starts at C, so at t = 0 the z-coords should be = 2, and you say it is just zero!

Comment: @O-BL: lookup your own answer. What's the $z$ of $C$ ?

Comment: let's see; hmm, so the second ant z equation is not correct since C is (2,2,0), I see; and it should be as you said in the answer, thank you a lot, that helped.